# Lyft Ride api response time is 6+ seconds

Tags: lyft-api

I am using the following API from Lyft developer console.

```
https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides?&start_time=2015-01-01T0:00:00+00:00%2B00%3A00&limit=20
```

When running on postman/rails it gives a response time of 6+ seconds. Why would a get API take this long?